# Python: how to run several scripts (or functions) at the same time under windows 7 multicore processor 64bit

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, multicore

sorry for this question because there are several examples in Stackoverflow. I am writing in order to clarify some of my doubts because I am quite new in Python language.

i wrote a function:

```
def clipmyfile(inFile,poly,outFile):
... # doing something with inFile and poly and return outFile
```

Normally I do this:

```
clipmyfile(inFile="File1.txt",poly="poly1.shp",outFile="res1.txt")
clipmyfile(inFile="File2.txt",poly="poly2.shp",outFile="res2.txt")
clipmyfile(inFile="File3.txt",poly="poly3.shp",outFile="res3.txt")
......
clipmyfile(inFile="File21.txt",poly="poly21.shp",outFile="res21.txt")
```

I had read in this example [Run several python programs at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126655/run-several-python-programs-at-the-same-time) and i can use (but probably i wrong)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(21)  # like in your example, running 21 separate processes
```

to run the function in the same time and speed my analysis

I am really honest to say that I didn't understand the next step.

Thanks in advance for help and suggestion
Gianni

Answer (score 1):

The map that is used in the example you provided only works for functions that recieve one argument. You can see a solution to this here: [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)

In your case what you would do is (assuming you have 3 arrays with files, polies, outs):

```
def expand_args(f_p_o):
    clipmyfile(*f_p_o)  

files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"] 
polis = ["poli1.txt", "poly2.txt"]
outis = ["out1.txt", "out2.txt"]
len_f = len(files)
p = Pool()
p.map(expand_args, [(files[i], polis[i], outis[i]) for i in xrange(len_f)])
```

Comment: Thanks!. p=Pool() need to be empty inside ()?

Comment: If I refer to the documentation, it can be empty, or you can define the number of process you want. The call is of the form multiprocessing.Pool([processes[, initializer[, initargs[, maxtasksperchild]]]])¶